# javascript - show/hide reset on new click

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

I have a list of products that when you click on the item, the info of the product will show. I have the show/hide working but where I'm having trouble is what I need to add into the javascript to hide the last item details when a new item is clicked. Currently the item information will show the newly clicked on info plus the info of the last item clicked.

HTML

```
<ul>
        <li><button onclick="product1()"><h4>Knee Brace L1843</h4></button></li>
        <li><button onclick="product2()"><h4>Wrist Brace L3807</h4></button></li>
        <li><button onclick="product3()"><h4>Wrist Brace</h4></button></li>
        <li><button onclick="product4()"><h4>Ankle Brace L1005</h4></button></li>
        <li><button onclick="product5()"><h4>Back Brace L0650</h4></button></li>
      </ul>

      <div id="product1info" class="hidden">
            <h2>Knee Brace L1843</h2>
            <p>Product Info</p>
        </div>

        <div id="product2info" class="hidden">
            <h2>Wrist Brace L3807</h2>
            <p>Product Info</p>
        </div>

        <div id="product3info" class="hidden">
            <h2>Wrist Brace</h2>
            <p>Product Info</p>
        </div>

        <div id="product4info" class="hidden">
            <h2>Ankle Brace L1005</h2>
            <p>Product Info</p>
        </div>

        <div id="product5info" class="hidden">
            <h2>Back Brace L0650</h2>
            <p>Product Info</p>
        </div>
```

JavaScript

```
function product1() {
    var x = document.getElementById("product1info");
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
        x.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "block";
    }
}

function product2() {
    var x = document.getElementById("product2info");
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
        x.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "block";

    }
}

function product3() {
    var x = document.getElementById("product3info");
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
        x.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "block";
    }
}

function product4() {
    var x = document.getElementById("product4info");
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
        x.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "block";
    }
}

function product5() {
    var x = document.getElementById("product5info");
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
        x.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think initially all the products should be invisible. You do not need multiple functions. Just pass corresponding id to the function call. In the function set all the products `display` property to none first, then show hide only the targeted product:

```js
function product(x) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.hidden').forEach(function(el){
    el.style.display = "none";
  });
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><button onclick="product(product1info)"><h4>Knee Brace L1843</h4></button></li>
  <li><button onclick="product(product2info)"><h4>Wrist Brace L3807</h4></button></li>
  <li><button onclick="product(product3info)"><h4>Wrist Brace</h4></button></li>
  <li><button onclick="product(product4info)"><h4>Ankle Brace L1005</h4></button></li>
  <li><button onclick="product(product5info)"><h4>Back Brace L0650</h4></button></li>
</ul>

<div id="product1info" class="hidden">
  <h2>Knee Brace L1843</h2>
  <p>Product Info</p>
</div>

<div id="product2info" class="hidden">
  <h2>Wrist Brace L3807</h2>
  <p>Product Info</p>
</div>

<div id="product3info" class="hidden">
  <h2>Wrist Brace</h2>
  <p>Product Info</p>
</div>

<div id="product4info" class="hidden">
  <h2>Ankle Brace L1005</h2>
  <p>Product Info</p>
</div>

<div id="product5info" class="hidden">
  <h2>Back Brace L0650</h2>
  <p>Product Info</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Would you be able to take a look at this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50934917/javascript-hide-div-info-on-click

Answer (score 1):

There's probably an easier way to do this but, in a nutshell what you want to do is hide ALL other products when one product is clicked, so you have to add that logic to each function as such:

```
function product1() {
 var x = document.getElementById("product1info");
 if (x.style.display === "block") {
     x.style.display = "none";
 } else {
     x.style.display = "block";
     document.getElementById("product2info").style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById("product3info").style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById("product4info").style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById("product5info").style.display = "none";
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Better way to do this :

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li><button onclick="displayProduct(1)"><h4>Knee Brace L1843</h4></button></li>
  <li><button onclick="displayProduct(2)"><h4>Wrist Brace L3807</h4></button></li>
  <li><button onclick="displayProduct(3)"><h4>Wrist Brace</h4></button></li>
  <li><button onclick="displayProduct(4)"><h4>Ankle Brace L1005</h4></button></li>
  <li><button onclick="displayProduct(5)"><h4>Back Brace L0650</h4></button></li>
</ul>

<div id="product1info" class="hidden product">
  <h2>Knee Brace L1843</h2>
  <p>Product Info</p>
</div>

<div id="product2info" class="hidden product">
  <h2>Wrist Brace L3807</h2>
  <p>Product Info</p>
</div>

<div id="product3info" class="hidden product">
  <h2>Wrist Brace</h2>
  <p>Product Info</p>
</div>

<div id="product4info" class="hidden product">
  <h2>Ankle Brace L1005</h2>
  <p>Product Info</p>
</div>

<div id="product5info" class="hidden product">
  <h2>Back Brace L0650</h2>
  <p>Product Info</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

JS:

```
function displayProduct(index) {
  var element = document.getElementById("product" + index + "info");
  var products = document.querySelectorAll(".product");

  products.forEach(function(product) {
    product.classList.add("hidden");
    product.classList.remove("visible");
  });

  element.classList.add("visible");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This way your products and buttons can be dynamically generated with a singular flyweight function.
Store product index on button `dataset` property as follows.. Reference a single `toggleProductInfo()` function. Optionally with a direct reference parameter to target `<button>` like `onclick="toggleProductInfo( this )"`

```
  <ul>
    <li><button data-product="1" onclick="toggleProductInfo()"><h4>Knee Brace L1843</h4></button></li>
    <li><button data-product="2" onclick="toggleProductInfo()"><h4>Wrist Brace L3807</h4></button></li>
    <li><button data-product="3" onclick="toggleProductInfo()"><h4>Wrist Brace</h4></button></li>
    <li><button data-product="4" onclick="toggleProductInfo()"><h4>Ankle Brace L1005</h4></button></li>
    <li><button data-product="5" onclick="toggleProductInfo()"><h4>Back Brace L0650</h4></button></li>
  </ul>
```

And the JS code

```
// - Keep a reference to the last product toggled (for performance, simplicity etc.)
let lastProductToggled = null

function toggleProductInfo( event ) {

    // - event parameter could be a direct reference to target <button> IF
    // <button onclick="toggleProductInfo( this )">
    var productId = "product" + event.target.dataset.product +  "info"
    var x = document.getElementById(productId);

    // - hide previous product IF not current (without looping through, and hiding all products' info only to display our target's)
    if ( null !== lastProductToggled && lastProductToggled !== productId ) {
        document.getElementById(lastProductToggled).style.display = "none"
    }

    // - toggle current product
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
        x.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "block";
    }

    // - save reference
    lastProductToggled = productId
}
```