# javascript - Hide div info on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show-hide

I have a list of products in a slider broken into 3 categories. When you click on a product, the product description appears. When you click on a new product, the old product description hides and the new product description appears.

My problem is when you change the categories I want the previous description to close and so that no descriptions are shown until you click a new product. Currently the product description is still showing of the last product from the last category until a new product is clicked.

I tried to write the javascript for this portion but failed. Can anyone help?

The javascript (the first 10 lines are the working code):

```
function product(x) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.hidden').forEach(function(el){
    el.style.display = "none";
  });
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}

var anav = document.querySelector('#navsliderselector');
var divprod = document.querySelector('.hidden');
button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
      if (menu.style.display == "") {
          menu.style.display = "none";

      } else {
          menu.style.display = "";

      }
    }
  );
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<ul>
                <li><button onclick="product(product1info)"><h4>Knee Brace L1843</h4></button></li>
                <li><button onclick="product(product2info)"><h4>Wrist Brace L3807</h4></button></li>
                <li><button onclick="product(product3info)"><h4>Wrist Brace</h4></button></li>
                <li><button onclick="product(product4info)"><h4>Ankle Brace L1005</h4></button></li>
                <li><button onclick="product(product5info)"><h4>Back Brace L0650</h4></button></li>
              </ul>

              <ul>
                <li><button onclick="product(product6info)"><h4>Back Brace L0650</h4></button></li>
              </ul>
               <ul>
                <li><button onclick="product(product7info)"><h4>Back Brace L0650</h4></button></li>
              </ul>

    <nav>
                <a href="#" id="navsliderselector">Braces</a>
                <a href="#" id="navsliderselector">Mobility</a>
                <a href="#" id="navsliderselector">Incontinence</a>
              </nav>

              <div id="product1info" class="hidden">
                    <h2>Knee Brace L1843</h2>
                    <p>Product Info</p>
                </div>

                <div id="product2info" class="hidden">
                    <h2>Wrist Brace L3807</h2>
                    <p>Product Info</p>
                </div>

                <div id="product3info" class="hidden">
                    <h2>Wrist Brace</h2>
                    <p>Product Info</p>
                </div>

                <div id="product4info" class="hidden">
                    <h2>Ankle Brace L1005</h2>
                    <p>Product Info</p>
                </div>

                <div id="product5info" class="hidden">
                    <h2>Back Brace L0650</h2>
                    <p>Product Info</p>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are writing the product function for all your onclicks wrong.

You write all your onclick functions with the number included in the function name:

```
<li><button onclick="product1()"><h4>Knee Brace L1843</h4></button></li>
```

Based on your given code there are no other product functions with numbers with them so that is the problem.

Since your product function takes a parameter x and modifies the display of it, I think you should be passing in the element itself into the parameter

so instead of this:

```
<li><button onclick="product1()"><h4>Knee Brace L1843</h4></button></li>
```

you should write this:

```
<li><button onclick="product(this)"><h4>Knee Brace L1843</h4></button></li>
```

**EDIT:**

Sorry, I seem to have misunderstood the question. If your purpose was to clear all product descriptions every time the client chooses a new product category then:

You can simply create a new onclick function that clears all descriptions(I'm going to use the implementation you did for your product function):

```
function clearAllDescriptions(){
  document.querySelectorAll('.hidden').forEach(function(el){
    el.style.display = "none";
  });
}
```

and then assign it to the navigation categories:

```
<a href="#" onclick="clearAllDescriptions()" id="navsliderselector">Braces</a>
<a href="#" onclick="clearAllDescriptions()" id="navsliderselector">Mobility</a>
<a href="#" onclick="clearAllDescriptions()" id="navsliderselector">Incontinence</a>
```

Comment: So you're saying if I change (1) to (this) my code should work?

Comment: Oh that's so simple! I was trying to over-complicate things! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function product(x) {
  $('.productDescr').hide();
  $('.productDescr[product=' + x + ']').fadeIn("fast");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".categoryLink:not(.active)", function() {
    $('.categoryLink.active').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    var categSel = $(this).attr("category");
    $('.categoryProducts').hide();
    $('.categoryProducts[category=' + categSel + ']').fadeIn("fast");
    $('.productDescr').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.productDescr {
display:none
}
.categoryLink {
display:inline-block;
padding:3px 5px;
background-color:lightgray;
border-radius:6px;
cursor:pointer
}
.categoryLink.active {
background-color:#07c;
color:white
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<nav>
  <a class="categoryLink active" category="1">Braces</a>
  <a class="categoryLink" category="2">Mobility</a>
  <a class="categoryLink" category="3">Incontinence</a>
</nav>

<ul class="categoryProducts" category="1">
  <li><button onclick="product(1)"><h4>Knee Brace L1843</h4></button></li>
  <li><button onclick="product(2)"><h4>Wrist Brace L3807</h4></button></li>
  <li><button onclick="product(3)"><h4>Wrist Brace</h4></button></li>
  <li><button onclick="product(4)"><h4>Ankle Brace L1005</h4></button></li>
  <li><button onclick="product(5)"><h4>Back Brace L0650</h4></button></li>
</ul>

<ul class="categoryProducts" category="2" style="display:none">
  <li><button onclick="product(6)"><h4>Back Brace L0650</h4></button></li>
</ul>
 <ul class="categoryProducts" category="3" style="display:none">
  <li><button onclick="product(7)"><h4>Back Brace L0650</h4></button></li>
</ul>

<div product="1" class="productDescr">
      <h2>Knee Brace L1843</h2>
      <p>Product Info</p>
  </div>

  <div product="2" class="productDescr">
      <h2>Wrist Brace L3807</h2>
      <p>Product Info</p>
  </div>

  <div product="3" class="productDescr">
      <h2>Wrist Brace</h2>
      <p>Product Info</p>
  </div>

  <div product="4" class="productDescr">
      <h2>Ankle Brace L1005</h2>
      <p>Product Info</p>
  </div>

  <div product="5" class="productDescr">
      <h2>Back Brace L0650</h2>
      <p>Product Info</p>
  </div>
  <div product="6" class="productDescr">
      <h2>Back Brace L0650</h2>
      <p>Product Info</p>
  </div>
  <div product="7" class="productDescr">
      <h2>Back Brace L0650</h2>
      <p>Product Info</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: When I click on my products the descriptions do not appear using this coding. It may be valuable to add this slider is already running jquery so the functionality of the products switching once clicking the category is already in place.